# Dimension of boundary value problem for homogeneous ODE $u''+u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the ODE $u''+u=0$ on $(0,\pi)$, what is the dimension for the vector space of solutions satisfying the boundary value problems;

1. $u(0)=u(\pi)$
2. $u(0)=u(\pi)=0$
3. What if $(0,\pi)$ is replaced with $(0,1)$?

I'm a little rusty on my diff EQ, so it's possible I'm neglecting some important detail.

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track here.

1. We know that the general solution to the homogeneous equation is given by $Csin(t)+Kcos(t)$.

Plugging in our boundary conditions, we get that $$Csin(0)+Kcos(0)=Csin(\pi)+Kcos(\pi)$$ $$C\cdot 0+ K\cdot 1 = C\cdot 0+K\cdot (-1),$$ which holds for any $C$ and $K=0$

So the space of solutions is just span{sin(t)}, and thus the dimension is 1.

2. Using the work from the previous problem, we can again conclude that $K=0$. But it's not clear to me if anything changes here. It seems like the work from the previous part of the problem worked for any arrangement where $u(0)=u(\pi)$. So shouldn't the same conclusion hold?
3. if we have $u(0)=u(1)$, then we get $$Csin(0)+Kcos(0)=Csin(1)+Kcos(1)$$
   And after a bit of algebra we have $$\frac{K(1-cos(1))}{sin(1)} = C$$

I'm not sure what exactly this last result means for the dimension of the solution space. I'm free to pick any value for $K$, but how does this translate to the dimension of the space of functions that solve the boundary value problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Part 2, you are right. Nothing will change.

For Part 3, from what you showed, the general solution of the ODE with the appropriate BVs becomes
$$u = K \left(\cos t + \frac{1- \cos 1}{\sin 1}\sin t \right) = K v$$

where $v = \left(\cos t + \frac{1- \cos 1}{\sin 1}\sin t \right)$

Thus, $v$ is the basis vector of the solution space, and its dimension $=1$